# Getting retweets

Tags: java, twitter4j

I would like to use twitter4j to collect data from user timelines.  But there is a problem: according to the twitter4j documentation,

> "For backwards compatibility reasons, retweets are stripped out of the user_timeline when calling in XML or JSON (they appear with 'RT' in RSS and Atom). If you'd like them included, you can merge them in from statuses retweeted_by_me."

The problem is that retweeted_by_me only gives me my own retweets, and I want retweets of other users.  Does anybody know a way to deal with this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "my own retweets" and "retweets of other users"? It doesn't sound like there's any issue, if I understand the documentation right.

Comment: @sphanley "My own retweets" means the retweets of the account whose credentials are used to authenticate the Twitter app.  "Retweets of other users" means the retweets of any other account.

Comment: So what you're looking for is a way to show the times that other people have retweeted tweets originally tweeted by the authenticated account, rather than other people's tweets which the authenticated account has retweeted? It seems pretty obvious that that isn't what "retweeted_by_me" would return.

Comment: @sphanley In fact, I am not interested in tweets which have anything to do with the authenticated user - I'm using app auth rather than user auth, so there isn't really an authenticated user anyway.  So it indeed seems clear that retweeted_by_me is of no use here, and the question remains: how to I get retweets from user timelines?